# How to tint one color of an imageview?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

I have icons that contains two colors when I switch to night mode I want only one of these two to be tinted.

Is that a way to do so ?

Comment: if its a vector then you might be able to do so using https://github.com/devendroid/VectorChildFinder. Find the path & change the color

Comment: @Gautam Is there a way without a third library/project ?

Comment: I am not aware of. I tried finding some android api but i couldn't so i used this and it worked really well for me

Answer (score 0):

You can take color from theme for your path :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportWidth="100"
    android:viewportHeight="100">
  <path
      android:fillColor="?colorPrimary"
      android:pathData="M 0 0 H 100 V 100 H 0 V 0 Z" />
</vector>
```

And if you have different values for attribute `<item name="colorPrimary">#D50000</item>` in `day/night` theme it will work as you want